# How to render alpha channeled animated 2D sprites in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: 2d, animation, opengl-es2

I searched, but I can't find **specifically** how to render animated 2D sprites with an **alpha channel** onto a 3D polygon, z=0, in OpenGL ES 2.0.

This is just a **basic 2D** concept, but since I'm using, **OpenGL ES 2.0**, I need to use 3D vertex data to render to the viewport. I'm also assuming I'll need a 0.01 like z-depth projection matrix.

I don't know if I **load** parts of the bitmap first onto the **texture data**, or just use a large texture and **manipulate the UV** onto the 2D/3D vertices? Should it all be done in a **shader**?, if so, how would that be done (using uniforms and attributes in a shader)? What is the best technique for this? When do I update the animation as well, in the draw function or a **separate** update function?

Comment: You should post your current draw and update code.

Comment: Have you tried using an orthographic projection? What else have you tried? Also, you might want to read http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch My post:May 4 '13 at 4:34 the other post asked Nov 1 '13 at 20:09

Comment: @mathacka: That post has an answer, this one doesn't. Marking a question as a duplicate isn't a judgment on you. It's just bookkeeping. Don't take it personally.